# PHP - Creating Arrays by Exploded Strings

Tags: php

I have some inputs that I need to process from a form.  The # of inputs from a form depends on the number of languages in my application.  For example, lets say I support english and french:

```
$input = array(
  'name_1' => 'Some input in english',
  'content_1' => 'Some long text in english',
  'name_2' => 'Some input in french',
  'content_2' => 'Some long text in french'
);
```

...Where '1' and '2' are the IDs of english and french respectively.  What I want to do is explode the strings:

```
foreach($input as $key=>$val)
{
  $exploded = explode('_', $key);
  $arr = $exploded[1];
  $key = $exploded[2];
}
```

..And then push them to separate arrays.  Keep in mind that there could be 2 languages, or 10, so just initializing 2 arrays and checking for '1' or '2' as the $key won't work.

How can I push the values of each to an array so that I end up with an array that look something like this?

```
$results = array( '1' => array('name' => 'Some input in english', 'content' => 'Some long text in english'), '2' => array('name' => 'Some input in french', 'content' => 'Some long text in french');
```

Thanks in advance.  One idea I had was to initialize 2 arrays based off a count of unique key values, but wanted to check first to see if there is a "right" way to do this for a function already there for something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
$results = array();
foreach($input as $key=>$val)
{
  $exploded = explode('_', $key);
  $results[$exploded[1]][$exploded[0]] = $val;
}
```