# Exploding a string into associative array keys

Tags: php

I have a set of strings that are formatted like "A.B.C" and can have varying 'depths'.  I.E. one might be just "A" or could be "A.B.C.D".

I want to be able to convert it into the keys for an associative array.  So "A" would translate to

```
$var["A"] = $val;
```

And "A.B" would translate to

```
$var["A"]["B"] = $val;
```

Comment: Cool story bro. What did you try?

Comment: I've seen several people doing similar things with fixed depth keys by using explode (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406462/php-creating-arrays-by-exploded-strings).  I, however, don't know the depth of the array in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access multidimensional array by string with delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520048/access-multidimensional-array-by-string-with-delimiter) - this is only one of the many duplicates. Please be a little more creative how to search for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive function and passing by `&reference`

```
$str = "A.B.C" ;

$letters = explode(".", $str);

$result = array() ;

function goDeep(&$array, $letters, $level){
  if ($level >= count($letters)){
    $array = "Your value here" ;
    return ;
  }

  $array[$letters[$level]] = array() ;
  goDeep($array[$letters[$level]], $letters, ++$level);
}

goDeep($result, $letters, 0);
var_dump($result);                 //3 - level deep array is ready.
```

Comment: I had to remove the initialization of "$array[$letters[$level]] = array();" to work with multiple passes, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be `eval()`.

```
<?php
    $a = "A.B.C";
    $temp = explode('.',$a);
    $keys = "";
    foreach ($temp as $value) {
        $keys .= "['$value']";
    }
    $val = "XXX";
    $var = array();
    eval('$var'.$keys.' = $val;');
    print_r($var);
?>
```

Result like :

```
Array ( [A] => Array ( [B] => Array ( [C] => XXX ) ) )
```

Comment: `$var` is an empty array. Indeces `A`, `B` will be undefined.

Comment: Did you run it ?
 I ran and got this result Array ( [A] => Array ( [B] => Array ( [C] => XXX ) ) ) . So,Indeces A,B cannot be undefined after run the eval code.

Comment: I kinda have no idea why it works :D

Comment: What about the usual warning that `eval` is **evil**? Especially if the string comes from user input!

Comment: Yes, eval is dangerous function to use. If you don't know anything about validation , you shouldn't use it.